# Color legends based on custom-fill colors using ggforce::geom_mark_ellipse()

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

I am trying to use custom colors for my plot and legends. However, when I run the code below, the legends disappear (see Fig. 1). The legends are present when I do not use custom colors to fill the ellipses (see Fig. 2). I will appreciate any suggestions.

**Fig. 1:**

[image]

**Fig. 2:**

[image]

```
library(palmerpenguins)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

penguins <- penguins %>%
  drop_na()
penguins %>% head() %>% print()
cols <- c("#0066cc","#9933ff","#66cc33")
my_color <- rep("", nrow(penguins))
cidx <- 0
for (color in unique(penguins$species)){
  cidx <- cidx + 1
  idx <- which(penguins$species == color)
  my_color[idx] <- cols[cidx]
}

p <- penguins %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = bill_length_mm,
             y = flipper_length_mm))+
  geom_mark_ellipse(aes(fill = I(my_color), alpha = I(0.2)),
  # geom_mark_ellipse(aes(fill = species),
                   expand = unit(0.5,"mm"),
                   size = 0) +
  geom_point(color = I(my_color))

plot(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve your requirements within the ggplot build-up using scales...

```r
library(palmerpenguins)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(tidyr)

penguins <- 
  penguins  |> 
  drop_na()


cols <- c("#0066cc","#9933ff","#66cc33")

penguins |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = bill_length_mm,
             y = flipper_length_mm))+
  geom_mark_ellipse(aes(fill = species),
                    colour = NA,
                    alpha = 0.2,
                    expand = unit(0.5,"mm"),
                    size = 0) +
  geom_point(aes(color = species))+
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = unique(penguins$species),
                    values = cols)+
  scale_colour_manual(breaks = unique(penguins$species),
                    values = cols)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks, but I do not want borders in the ellipses

Comment: Just noticed this and updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten the code substantially by using `after_scale`

```r
library(palmerpenguins)
library(ggforce)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

ggplot(tidyr::drop_na(penguins),
       aes(bill_length_mm, flipper_length_mm, color = species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_mark_ellipse(aes(fill = after_scale(alpha(colour, 0.2))),
                    expand = unit(0.5, "mm"), size = 0) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#0066cc","#66cc33","#9933ff"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks for showing another approach. Interestingly in your solution alpha has no impact on the plot!

Comment: @WasimAftab that's because the alpha is specified inside `after_scale`

Comment: what I meant was your code is drawing ellipses even if alpha is 0, which makes this parameter lose its usefulness

Comment: @WasimAftab I'm pretty sure changing  `after_scale(alpha(colour, 0.2))` to `after_scale(alpha(colour, 0))` will set the alpha to 0.

Comment: No, that's not correct. I double checked. interestingly, your snippet runs even for `after_scale(alpha(colour, -1000))`

Comment: @WasimAftab in that case, you can do `aes(fill = after_scale(colour)), alpha = 0` which definitely does work